# Proper Tag Synonym Vote Buttons

Tags: script, tags

### Screenshot / Code Snippet

[image]

### About

There's a new [tag synonym dashboard](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/329687/295232), which looks nice except for those thumbs up/down buttons. Since we're Stack Exchange, not Facebook, they should be the familiar triangles instead. I've posted an [answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/329688/295232) asking for a change; that was [status-declined](/questions/tagged/status-declined), so this userscript aims to fill the gap.

#### Download

You can install the script from [this direct GitHub link](https://github.com/Glorfindel83/SE-Userscripts/raw/master/tag-synonym-vote-buttons/tag-synonym-vote-buttons.user.js). The source code can be downloaded [here](https://github.com/Glorfindel83/SE-Userscripts/blob/master/tag-synonym-vote-buttons/tag-synonym-vote-buttons.user.js); if you want the buttons in horizontal mode, feel free to change it for personal use.

#### Platform

Developed and tested with ViolentMonkey, Firefox and macOS, but I expect no platform/browser/extension differences.

Comment: Im glad i dont have access to that page because honestly that default part looks like trash! This script should be the default, good work :)